# What is a Safek Muchlat? (i.e. unsure if he's a full-fledged Metzora)

Tags: mishna, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, safek, tzaraas-negaim, maseches-nazir

The Mishna in [Nazir 8:2](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01161.html#HtmpReportNum0054_L2) (Daf 59b and various other times in tractate Nazir) discusses a person who may or may not be a Metzora that is supposed to be sent out of the city walls.

To quote with the Bartenura:

> נָ**זִיר שֶׁהָיָה טָמֵא בְסָפֵק וּמֻחְלָט בְּסָפֵק**. סָפֵק אִם נִטְמָא בְמֵת **וְסָפֵק אִם הוּא מְצֹרָע מֻחְלָט**‏

Question: **What is the case of somebody who is סָפֵק אִם הוּא מְצֹרָע מֻחְלָט - unsure if he's a full-fledged Metzora)?**

I don't see anybody, here or in the Talmud, giving a specific case of how this happens.

Keep in mind that in [Mishna 9:4](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01161.html#HtmpReportNum0058_L2) of Nazir we learn that if there's a doubt if somebody is a Metzora, then the rule is:

- If he has previously been declared a Metzora, then he remains such.
- If he has not yet been declared a Metzora then - in doubt - he is not a Metzora.

**So we never seem to have a case of somebody who is סָפֵק אִם הוּא מְצֹרָע מֻחְלָט - unsure if he's a full-fledged Metzora.**

[Mishna 9:4](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01161.html#HtmpReportNum0058_L2) of Nazir in context:

> כָּל סְפֵק נְגָעִים בַּתְּחִלָּה, טָהוֹר עַד שֶׁלֹּא נִזְקַק לַטֻּמְאָה. מִשֶּׁנִּזְקַק לַטֻּמְאָה, סְפֵקוֹ טָמֵא.‏
>
> **ר"ע מברטנורה**
>   **כָּל סְפֵק נְגָעִים בַּתְּחִלָּה טָהוֹר**. כְּגוֹן שְׁנַיִם שֶׁבָּאוּ אֵצֶל כֹּהֵן, בָּזֶה בַּהֶרֶת כִּגְרִיס וּבָזֶה בַּהֶרֶת כְּסֶלַע, וּבְסוֹף שָׁבוּעַ בָּזֶה כְּסֶלַע וּבָזֶה כְּסֶלַע, וְאֵין יָדוּעַ בְּאֵיזֶה מֵהֶן פָּשָׂה, שְׁנֵיהֶן טְהוֹרִין, וְאַף עַל גַּב דְּוַדַּאי אֶחָד מֵהֶן טָמֵא:‏
>  **מִשֶּׁנִּזְקַק לַטֻּמְאָה סְפֵקוֹ טָמֵא**. כְּגוֹן שְׁנַיִם שֶׁבָּאוּ אֵצֶל כֹּהֵן, בָּזֶה בַּהֶרֶת כִּגְרִיס וּבָזֶה כְּסֶלַע, וּבְסוֹף שָׁבוּעַ בָּזֶה כְּסֶלַע וְעוֹד וּבָזֶה כְּסֶלַע וְעוֹד, חָזְרוּ לִהְיוֹת כְּסֶלַע, אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁהָאֶחָד מֵהֶם וַדַּאי טָהוֹר, שֶׁכְּבָר הָלַךְ הַפִּשְׂיוֹן, שְׁנֵיהֶם טְמֵאִים, כֵּיוָן שֶׁנִּזְקְקוּ לַטֻּמְאָה, עַד שֶׁיַּחְזְרוּ לְכִגְרִיס:‏

Comment: I didn't think enough, but the nafka mina is the need of korbanot, he is tame but the korbanot chatat is chatat haof that comes in case of safek and is not eaten.